# After babel/parser generates ast, immediately use babel/generator to output, the results are inconsistent

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-parser

```
const { parse } = require('@babel/parser')
const generator = require('@babel/generator')

const source = `const babel = {
  version() {},
  author: ''
};`

const ast = parse(source)

console.log(generator.default(ast).code === source) // false

console.log(generator.default(ast).code)
/*
const babel = {
  version() {},

  author: ''
};
*/
```

**One more space after the `version` function**

I slightly modified the implementation of the version function. From the previous `FunctionExpression` to the current `ArrowFunctionExpression`, the result is in line with expectations.

```
const { parse } = require('@babel/parser')
const generator = require('@babel/generator')

const source = `const babel = {
  version: () => {},
  author: ''
};`

const ast = parse(source)

console.log(generator.default(ast).code === source) // true
```

What should I do to keep them consistent?

Comment: I tried to modify the second parameter (GeneratorOptions) of the generator function, but it didn’t work

Answer (score 2):

Babel is focused on performing transformations to the code from the standpoint of programmatic behavior, so it only makes a small amount of effort to reproduce the original formatting. Given that, this is expected behavior.

In the case you're seeing, it appears that the formatting you expect does not match what your Babel version happens to output. If formatting is important, I'd recommend running the code through `prettier` afterward to give it consistent formatting.

Comment: The newline coming from nowhere is still a bit weird though, don't you think?

Comment: @Bergi I can't argue there, in this specific case I don't know why the newline is there. At the core though, there is nothing about Babel's logic that guarantees that `generator(parse(source)).code === source`.

Comment: I am also here to ask if this is in line with expectations. As https://github.com/JLHwung said, users can be prompted in the document.

Comment: @Link Sorry I don't understand what you are asking. As far as "expectations" here, I'd say that Babel can output any amount of whitespace and still match "expectations".